# Top bar embiggened?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar

I noticed this as I was refreshing pages left open from yesterday. The top bar is a few pixels deeper than it was, and there's a one pixel wide almost white stripe beneath it.
Hard to see the white stripe on this, which was my only site I hadn't refreshed that uses a non-white header, before & after…

[image: before] [image: after]

& the same crop on Meta where the stripe is easier to see

[image]

Partly-scrolled image from Sound Design to confirm the stripe is actually part of the top bar…

[image]

Images from Safari but I checked Chrome is the same.
The bar depth difference itself is barely noticeable, the white stripe is irritating.
Bug or intentional?

Comment: We're making room for Ads .... pixel by pixel so you won't notice.

Comment: Looks like they just added a bottom border for some odd reason. Maybe a designer thought it look more "modern"... :/

Comment: bigger screens — bigger bars

Comment: I can see this on all Stacks where the top bar (with the search and the icons) and the Stack 'personalized' title bar are both not white, and I suspect it on Stacks where the top bar is white (e.g., Stack Overflow).

Comment: A little bit of careful and slow scrolling does confirm that it's a change to the top bar.

Comment: Yup. It's most irritating on the ones with darker themes, & easy to confirm it is indeed part of the top bar itself. I've added a partly-scrolled crop from sound design to show this up more clearly.

Comment: [scifi.se] provides a very clear example...

Comment: Eew, I thought it looked bad on our [crypto.se] site.

Comment: @Mithical you win!

Comment: Related on RPG.SE meta: [Something about the site layout changed, adding an unsightly line between the top bar and the site graphic](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12430)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ *cries in small screens

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The white horizontal line is a bug. GitHub was down yesterday when we went to push a fix out. Should go out today.

The increased height (4px to be exact) is by design.

Comment: Thank you for the info & good to know the stripe will go. Is there any reasoning for the extra 4px depth? As I currently view this page at about the size of a sheet of A4, barely taking up one half of one screen, of a pair of 27" displays, in these days of increasing numbers who use phones, pads & ever-smaller laptops, it seems we have screen estate issues not seen since the 90s & feels somewhat counter-intuitive.

Comment: @Tetsujin This increase alongside the removal of shadows in the sidebar/topbar (also shipped yesterday) were some minor updates in response to feedback regarding accessibility. The goal for these changes is to help the site feel less cluttered. We do want to be cognizant of smaller screens when we make these changes and I appreciate that reminder. In this case, I think the 4 px increase won't cause a major loss of information for the bulk of the users on the network.

Comment: Again, thank you for the info. Personally, I doubt the extra 4 pixels will ever cause me any stress ;))The white line was the irritating bit. [Though if asked, I'd prefer the whole top bar would scroll out of view with the page, not stick in place. I can be back at the top of any page with a single button-press should I need it. I get that it provides identity, but again it's a screen estate issue.]  I have the left sidebar disabled, so never noticed it.

Comment: @Piper whose feedback was it leading to the change? Internal, or on a meta site?

Comment: @Tetsujin There are user scripts to get rid of the sticky top bar. I use https://gist.github.com/vyznev/7c9a7ddc5c057d4c895864e460b4a88d/raw/se_no_sticky_topbar.user.js and it works fantastically. Makes the sites much cleaner!

Comment: After the fix, there is still a newly-introduced light line between rpg.se's top bar and header art.  [Site meta question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12430/something-about-the-site-layout-changed-adding-an-unsightly-line-between-the-to), [screenshot of current state](https://i.imgur.com/dQaLWwg.png), [screenshot of previous state](https://i.imgur.com/RqTYV2n.png)

Comment: Stripes gone this morning 06:00 GMT - https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGafY.png